# RDLC - Using RDLC in AspDotNet Core Project - An error occurred during local report processing. Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: asp.net-core, reporting, rdlc

How to fix : Using RLDC in AspNet Core Project with AspNetCore.ReportingServices thorws an exception as
***"An error occurred during local report processing. Index was outside the bounds of the array."***

1. I have .Net Winforms project to add RDLC files. I always copy/paste rdlc files + datasources in AspNet Core Project.
2. Trying to export pdf/excel and it throws above exception.

Note: It's random. It comes sometime. But it often when deploy on IIS Server. Any suggestions/recommendations or help will be appreciated highly.

Exception: Exception is in AspNetCore.ReportingServices nuget package that we include in our DontNetCore project. Here is the stacktrace.

"at AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
at AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
at AspNetCore.Reporting.InternalLocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)
at AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalReport.Execute(RenderType renderType, Int32 pageIndex, Dictionary`2 parameters, String findString) at Tracs4Life.Service.ReportService.<GenerateReportAsync>d__21.MoveNext() in C:\D drive\MySpace\CompanyProjects\BsiTracks4Life\Source\Tracs4Life\Tracs4Life.Service\ReportService.cs:line 572 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Tracs4Life.Website.Controllers.ReportController.d__11.MoveNext() in C:\D drive\MySpace\CompanyProjects\BsiTracks4Life\Source\Tracs4Life\Tracs4Life.Website\Controllers\ReportController.cs:line 211".

Comment: I am also facing this problem, did you solve this problem? why did it happen?

Comment: @Sraban75 It's issue with AspNetCore.ReportingServices. This library is no longer being supported, even developer is not replying. If you see code of AspNetCore.ReportingServices in detail  it caching data when Render method called. If remove caching lines and try to used compiled DLLs in your project instead of nuget package. I haven't tried but may be it can solve the issue. What I did? I just remove all possible expressions statements in .rdlc file and tried to format data in model in related reporting services of my project and issue was resolved.

Comment: But it's not the perfect solution. Better to use some paid solutions with DotNet Core i.e DevExpress, syncfusion etc. Otherwise use webform/window package in  web form / windows app.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any expressions, the report will fail.
This is a limitation of this library